# Passing data using redirect() + frame URL pattern in Django

Tags: django, url, redirect, view

I want to redirect to **URL along with parameter** using **redirect()** method.

**Current view function** is just like below but it is not passing any parameters

```
def add(request):
    # Do something
    return redirect('/register/')
```

How can I **pass parameters** using redirect()

```
def add(request):
    # Do something
    return redirect('/register/', {"key1": "value1"})
```

Need to pass parameter like `{"key1": "value1"}`

**Current URL pattern:**

```
url(r'^register/$', views.index, name="register_index")
```

May I want to change URL pattern when I want to pass parameters to same url ?

Comment: what's wrong with `redirect('/register/?key1=value1')`?

Comment: look into using `reverse`

Comment: @DmitryB.: Is there any another way ?

Comment: @xthestreams: Can you please explain to use `reverse` ?

Comment: @iNikkz look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/ they have a good example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your case. I think you should use reverse because of you do not hard code link, use only change name url.py and do not change your code.

```
  from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
  def add(request):
        # Do something
        return redirect('register_index')
```

Howerver with url have  parameter.I have a example

urls.py

```
  url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.show_detail, name='author_detail'),
```

view.py

```
 def view_detail(request):
     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('author_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}))
```

Comment: @Son Lam: Thanks. But there is an error in your code.. Only reverse() is not working. You need to use `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('author_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}))`. Just edit your answer. It will help others and I make your answer correct.

Comment: @iNikkz: I have just fix. This is my mistake. Thanks